# Intersection with non unique items in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two arrays and i want the intersection of them including duplicate items:

```
a = [0, 0, 1, 4, 5]
b = [0, 4, 6]


set(a) & set(b)
>>> [0, 4] #Result
```

If i do this the result not include duplicates elements

I would like to return :

```
>>> [0, 0, 4]
```

Ideas??

Comment: But `0` does not occur twice in `b`? Furthermore why does `4` not occur twice since it is both in `a` and `b`.

Comment: What's the expected output if `a = [0, 0]` and `b = [0, 0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming only `a` has duplicates, you can use:

```
[i for i in a if i in b]
```

Answer (score 1):

Set operation works for unique elements only in Python. You might want to use list comprehension for this

```
Result = [element for element in a if element in b]
```